# Python teradatasql lib How to combine use {fn teradata_write_csv} & {teradata_field_sep }

Tags: python, teradatasql

Python  teradatasql lib  How to combine use {fn teradata_write_csv} & {teradata_field_sep }  ?  Thanks !

I use this like pic and show error , I cant find any example.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using the most current version of teradatasql? The teradata_field_sep escape function is fairly new.

Comment: 17.10.0.8 version!
maybe must upgrade to 17.10.0.11